# Tag Request: "Angular" (Angular is not Angular.js)

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am not at 1500 rep, so I cannot create tags, but the [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag does not exist on Code Review. I just asked a question and had to tag it with [angular.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular.js), which is only version 1.0 according to the Angular community.

Comment: Related discussion in chat a while ago: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36941581#36941581

Answer (score 6):

It seems like Stack Overflow does this differentiation, so we might as well do it:

- SO's [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info): *Use for questions about AngularJS, the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the "angular" tag.*
- SO's [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info): *Questions about Angular, the web framework from Google, including versions 2, 4, and all succeeding versions. Use this tag for questions which are not specific to an individual version. For the older AngularJS web framework, use the angularjs tag.*

In addition both have some associated synonyms:

- angularjs: angular.js, angular1.x
- angular: angular2, angular4, angular4.x

To reduce confusion I would suggest that we keep the same tags as used on Stack Overflow, that is `angularjs` for the older stuff, and `angular` for the newer stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I've messed around with Angular.js before, but have yet to try Angular (Angular 2+).
But looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(application_platform)) it looks like Angular 2+ is not compatible with Angular.js.
It's also not that much like what I remember Angular.js to be.

If this were just a normal version upgrade such as Angular 2+ v2 and v4, then I'd not recommend another tag.
But due to library incompatibilities I've decided to create the [angular-2+](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular-2%2b),
this is as Angular also goes by this name, and is unlikely to get Angular.js questions tagged with it.
But also because Angular 2+ already has a fourth version out, and so saying your using Angular 2 v4 is a bit strange, when Angular v1 is Angular.js.

---

If this gets down-voted to oblivion, remove the tag, :)

Comment: The angular community calls Angular 1.x "angular.js" and Angular 2+ as "angular." It can be confusing, certainly.

Comment: @Jeff Even more so when you can refer to both of them as Angular, ;P

Comment: Typically, tags should reflect what the community who reviews the code, would expect.

Comment: @rolfl Yes, the community refers to Angular 2+ as to "Angular". Whereas, Angular 1 is almost always called "Angular.JS". They are truly two different things which have very few in common and keep diverging over time. I am 100% in favor of having two separate tags.

Comment: How will future versions of Angular affect this naming scheme?

Comment: @Mast You'd change 'angular-2+' to whatever they're calling it after the future version of Angular, if that's 'angular-2-5' or 'angular-middle-version' that's fine. The new Angular tag we'd make would be called whatever they're calling it, unless it's 'angular', if it's 'angular' call it a recognised alternate name. As changing the meaning of the tag 'angular' one day seems beyond confusing.

Answer (score 4):

This link explains [framework developers' perspective](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html).

> Three simple guidelines:
>
> - Use “Angular” for versions 2.0.0 and later (e.g. “I’m an Angular developer”, “This is an Angular meetup”, “The Angular ecosystem is growing quickly”)
> - Use "AngularJS" to describe versions 1.x or earlier
>   Use the version number “Angular 4.0” "Angular 2.4" when needed to talk about a specific release (e.g. when talking about a newly introduced feature - “This is an introduction to feature X, introduced in Angular 4”, “I’m proposing this change for Angular 5”)
> - Use full semver version when reporting a bug (e.g. “This issue is present as of Angular 2.3.1”)

Comment: This even further accentuates why `angularjs` and `angular` should be the final tags used by us.