# No tag for Angular

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There is no tag for Angular (v2, 4, 5). It redirects to Angular.js, which is a completely different framework using a different language. Is it possible to create a new tag for [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the tag to use would be [angular-2+](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular-2%2b), which was [created 8 months ago](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7287/23788), albeit without an obvious community consensus or a tag wiki. I've looked up the synonym [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag on Stack Overflow, and added this summary:

> Use this tag on posts involving code written with versions 2 & above of Angular, the web framework from Google. use the angular.js tag for posts involving the older AngularJS (1.x) framework.

The tag is there, we might as well use it. I encourage the community to [edit the tag wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3345) as needed.

Given how Stack Oveflow synonymizes [angular2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular2), [angular4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular4), and [angular4.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular4.x) with [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular), creating version-specific tags on CR doesn't strike me as an immediate necessity.

---

Given that we're several months after multiple discussions involving these tags,  and since [angular] is still a synonym of [angular.js] and [angular-js], and that throughout all these discussions, the rather obvious consensus is that *angular and angular-js aren't the same thing*, I've gone ahead and deleted the synonym, created an actual standalone [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag, and suggested it as a synonym of [angular-2+](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular-2%2b) - [vote it up/down here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/angular-2%2b/synonyms)

- Approving the synonym will make the [currently] single post tagged with [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular), to appear tagged as [angular-2+](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular-2%2b).
- Rejecting the synonym means [angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular) falls in limbo and would need to be re-synonymized with [angular-js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular-js), which goes against the apparent consensus.

Comment: How about making `angular-2+` a synonym of `angular`?

Comment: @DanielKucal that's exactly what I did (I was editing the post when you commented) =)

Comment: Oh okay then, I thought it'd work inversely and `angular` will redirect to `angular-2+` and the ugly tag will still be in use ;-)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean - yeah tag synonyms are confusing! [tag:angular] *will* redirect to [tag:angular-2+], since 2+ will be the "master" - it has to, it's used on 39 posts, whereas [tag:angular] didn't really exist, so it can't be the "master" without bumping every single one of these 39 posts back onto the front page (*before* the synonym is created), where we'd much rather have posts that are actually active. Besides, 2+ might be rather ugly, but it clears any confusion when you tag with "angular" and your post shows up as "angular-2+", which is accurate.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to be consistent with StackOverflow and just edit these 39 posts? It doesn't seem a lot

Comment: Stack Overflow's home page swallows 39 posts within a minute. Code Review's home page, ...*a bit* longer - besides, there's little to no benefit in doing that, since tagging with [tag:angular] will put it in the same search results as [tag:angular-2+]. That's what synonyms are for!

Comment: And think about subtags like `angular-bootstrap` etc., I'm sure they will be created just like this one, not `angular minus 2 plus` =) I think it will be confusing

Comment: [tag:angular-bootstrap] already exists

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean. Subtags will look just like this one, no one will create `angular-2+-bootstrap`, `angular-2+-material` etc, it will be inconsistent with main tag and the goal is to make it clear, right?

Comment: I would remove such a tag if I saw it. Use [angular-bootstrap] *in conjunction with* the proper [angular] | [angular-js] tag, and problem solved.

Comment: Actually [angular-bootstrap] has the following description: "Bootstrap helpers module for AngularJS framework."... At the beginning on SO there was [angular2] tag and then they moved everything just to [angular], although there was many more posts but it's worth it to avoid conflicts like this... Also the [angular] tag already has more followers than [angular-2+], too bad you don't agree with the community ( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°)

Comment: SO has angular2, angular4, and angular4.x tags, and they're all synonymized with angular, which means *there is no question tagged angular2-3-4x* anymore, everything goes to the master tag, i.e. angular. *If the community agrees with flooding the front page with angular posts, be my guest* - but I will not single-handedly edit 39 posts just to make a pedantic fix that brings little to no benefit: *they're synonyms*, which means if you're following [angular], you'll have [angular-2+] posts highlighted all the same. I'd suggest seeking consensus about the flooding before making any changes.

Comment: I'm confused how rejecting the synonym means that [angular] must be a synonym with [angular-js]. It may mean that we don't think we should have an angular tag

Comment: @Peilonrayz or that, yes. Which doesn't sound like what the community wants. I assumed we wanted to keep the Angular tag around..